# List users who can alter configuration of postgresql database

Tags: database, postgresql, database-administration

I am looking to get the list of users who have access to modify the configuration of PostgreSQL database. This is in order to make sure that only restricted user are authorized to modify Database configuration.

Comment: What have you tried, where is your code?

Comment: acutally i am looking for any table which have this information? Like which user have what type of privilages.

Comment: Actually i am looking for any table which have this information? Like which user have what type of privileges.  (similar to DBA_SYS_PRIVS in Oracle).

Comment: Are you referring to changes done through `ALTER SYSTEM`?

Comment: yes ALTER SYSTEM privileges to users.